# Filter 2 choices in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

can anyone show me the script to filter 2 or more choices within a column ?

For example:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F   G
1  x  x  x  x  x  AAA
3  x  x  x  x  x  BBB
4  x  x  x  x  x  AAA
1  x  x  x  x  x  CCC
4  x  x  x  x  x  CCC
5  x  x  x  x  x  AAA
```

I would want to filter "AAA" and "BBB", in one go. I have tried with:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import openpyxl 
from numpy.random import choice

df = pd.read_excel('filepath', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

df_sample = df.loc[df['G'].str.contains("AAA", 'BBB")]
```

But it only returns column G with "AAA", but "BBB" is not in.

Please guide me on how to do that.

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains` with the `|` separator :

```py
df[df.G.str.contains("AAA|BBB")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isin` or `contains`, but remember:

- `isin` checks if each value in the column is contained in a list of arbitrary values.
- `isin` works column-wise and is available for all data types.
- `contains` checks if arbitrary values are contained in each value in the column.
- `contains` works element-wise and makes sense only when dealing with strings (or values that can be represented as strings).

---

Here's an approach using `isin` :

```
choices_to_keep = ["AAA", 'BBB"]

filtered_df = df.G.isin(choices_to_keep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two parameters to the contains function, from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

> `Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=None, regex=True)`

Your function is equivalent to

`df['G'].str.contains(pat="AAA", case="BBB")`

The string `"BBB"` is treated as `True` in python, so your code is equivalent to-

`df['G'].str.contains(pat="AAA", case=True)`

That's why you're only getting the results for `"AAA"` to get the correct solution you can follow @Nathan Furnal's solution

```
df[df.G.str.contains("AAA|BBB")]
```